# Radio button returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm having a problem submitting form values to a php script that is not passing the radio buttons for some reason. I've read several many posts on here about this problem, but they weren't selecting any radio buttons on submission. My form has one of the radio buttons selected by default so there's no way this can return undefined. Here's the HTML:

```
<input type='radio' name='bFilterHistoryDate' id='bFilterHistoryDateBefore' value='before'  checked />
<input type='radio' name='bFilterHistoryDate' id='bFilterHistoryDateAfter' value='after' />
```

Here's the php:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Here's the returned output:

```
Array
(
[btnHistoryClear] => *
[btnHistoryAdd] => +
[btnHistoryDel] => -
[btnHistoryUpdate] => Update
[hidHistoryID] => 0
[eHistoryDate] => 
[sHistoryAction] => purchased
[sHistoryTag] => 
[sHistoryNote] => 
[sFilterHistoryCreator] => 1
[bFilterHistoryDateBefore] => undefined
[bFilterHistoryDateAfter] => undefined
[sFilterHistoryDate] => 2014-6-26
[sFilterHistoryAction] => 
[sFilterHistoryTag] => 
[asset] => 71
)
```

As you can see, the form values are being passed! I have no clue what's up with the radio buttons.  Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have some Javascript running on this page? Because the name of your radio button is `bFilterHistoryDate`, so that should be the index in the `$_POST` array. Instead, the array has the two ids of your radio buttons.

Comment: I would make sure that your radio buttons really are inside the `<form>`, and also use the browser debugging tools to check the browser's version of the outgoing HTTP request.

Comment: How are you posting this?  Are you using javascript at all, and if you so, can you post that code?  `$_POST['bFilterHistoryDate']` should contain the value of your radio button group.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've effectively created two different radio button groups by having different IDs.  Try removing the ID from both of them (as it's not needed) <strike>or make the IDs the same</strike>.  This probably wont matter, but change all of your single quotes to double quotes to be in compliance with the HTML spec.

Comment: Bad advice, you should never have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: Good catch.  Typing up answers too fast!

Answer (score 0):

your code run in my machine ,i got checked check box value in post print time.

```
Array
(
    [bFilterHistoryDate] => after
    [submit] => submit
)
```

I don't know why you get

```
[bFilterHistoryDateBefore] => undefined
[bFilterHistoryDateAfter] => undefined.
```

Why it display with id, actually it display name wise, both have common name   **bFilterHistoryDate**.